# Javascript REST API clearing error state

Tags: rest, error-handling

I am working on a SharePoint web app, and using the cross-domain library. I am looking for ways to recover from errors that the deferred functions return, and was wondering if SharePoint REST API has some object that keeps the error states which I can reset with a simple statement, something like in this fictitious example: `SP.ErrorManager.errorState.reset();`.

In other word, when I am searching for a record, for example if my `deferredCall.done(function (error) {// do something with error });` was called with some error, is some internal error variable set, and if it is how do I reset it?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if there is a global error variable, SharePoint maintains MANY JS environment variables on each page, so it's possible -- it's much more common though to handle errors as part of the XHR call (jQuery or otherwise) they originated from. Are you looking for some specific behavior? What library/libraries are you using? Older versions of jQuery use some sort of 'global' error variable, but newer ones do not. Examples may help shed some light on your situation.

Comment: I may be over-thinking this. I make a cross-domain call using SP.RequestExecutor to update a file and if it fails I will try to repeat the query, but feel like if an error state is set my second attempt may have troubles along the way. I was going to 'reset' the error state just in case.